# Click event firing after dragging

Tags: angular

Hey I'm using Angular material Drag and drop. Everything is working fine but after each drag it triggers the click event and it's really annoying. How can I stop this?

```
<div
  cdkDrag
  [cdkDragDisabled]="shiftWorker.locked"
  (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded(job, shiftWorker, $event)"
  (cdkDragStarted)="onDragStart($event)"
  [cdkDragData]="job"
  *ngIf="job.timelineInfo.isInDayShift === firstHalfDay"
  (click)="openWorkDetails(job.id)"
></div>
```

Comment: In the body of `onDragEnded` add `$event.preventDefault();`. Does that fix the issue? (*this assumes that `$event` is also the name of the 3rd parameter in that method*)

Comment: @Igor Tried that. When using this, the dragEnd functionality doesn't work, but the click event still happens :/

Comment: Have you tried $event.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: @Tim doesn't change anything sadly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a boolean to keep a track of this situation:

```
 var dragging = false;
 (cdkDragStarted): function(event, ui) {
    dragging = true;
    ...your code
 }

(click): function(event) {
    if (!dragging) {
        ...your code
    }
    else {
        dragging = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: need to do same onDrageEnd

Comment: Ended up doing this. Didn't need to do the same on onDragEnd. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked. The one from Martin did not.

Comment: @AvinKavish `onDragEnded` should **not** reset dragging, since it will be called before click and hence would always reset the flag -> would trigger click after dragging

Comment: You can reset dragging on (cdkDragDropped) if you need click events

Answer (score 5):

Turning off pointer events for the element while it's being dragged prevents a click event afterwards:

template:

```
<div cdkDrag #draggable="cdkDrag" 
     [class.pointer-events-none]="draggable._dragRef.isDragging()" ...
```

styles.scss:

```
.pointer-events-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```