# Differentiate cdkDrag and click in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a draggable element for which I have used `cdkDrag` and it is working fine for me. Now, I need to toggle a flag on click of the element. But when I drag the element and on drop the click event triggers. Can you please suggest how to work with `cdkDrag` and `click` together. Sharing the code snippet for the same.

```
        <div class="draggable-content" cdkDragBoundary=".drop-area" cdkDrag>
          <div class="min-workspace-view" *ngIf="showMinWorkspace === true">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="workspace" class="workspace-icon"
              (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); showMinWorkspace = !showMinWorkspace">
            </mat-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The expectation is: when the element dragged then click should not trigger. when the element is just clicked then drag event should not trigger.

Comment: same question with me. Looking for an answer. Did you solve this?

Comment: i've posted a different solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61662746/5155810

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got a solution to this.

You need a boolean property. Let's call it `dragging`.

On your `cdkDrag` element, add a `cdkDragStarted` callback, which sets this property to `true`. Then in your `click` callback, if that `this.dragging` is true, then set it to false and return. Hey Presto!

working stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-and-clickable-element

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I have resolved this issue exactly the same way. Any how marking your answer as correct one. Thanks for the help